# How to display category name and description on same page as list of posts from that category PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system

Is it possible someone could help me with a query.Any help would really be appreciated .Im using a cms from github for the back end of my site and wanted to add some queries to it. Its a basic enough categories and posts cms . On the site when You click on the name of a category you will come to a page with a list of posts from that category. Along with the lists of posts on that page i would like to add the name , a description and an image perhaps about the category the posts are from. Imagine a page with an artist as the category and posts list are paintings on the same page.
This is the database tables and code that displays list of posts
This is the site im using for my back end
https://github.com/Anik-Roy/CMS-BLOG
The category name is inserted when sending the post from a dropdown menu from the categories table

this is the table for the posts
CREATE TABLE `admin_panel` (
`id` int(10) NOT NULL,
`datetime` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`title` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`category` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`author` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`image` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`post` varchar(10000) NOT NULL

Category table
CREATE TABLE `category` (
`id` int(10) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`description` varchar(200) NOT NULL
`creatorname` varchar(200) NOT NULL

blog.php

```
<?php
        global $connection;

        if(isset($_GET['Submit'])) {
          $search = $_GET['Search'];
          $ViewQuery = "select * from admin_panel
            where datetime like '%$search%' or title like '%$search%' or category like '%$search%'
            or author like '%$search%' or post like '%$search%' order by id desc";
        } else if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
          $pageNumber = $_GET['page'];
          $showPostFrom = $pageNumber*5-5;

          global $connection;
          $queryPagination = "select count(*) from admin_panel";
          $executePagination = mysqli_query($connection, $queryPagination);
          $rowPagination = mysqli_fetch_array($executePagination);
          $totalPost = array_shift($rowPagination);
          $postPerPage = ceil($totalPost/5);

          if($pageNumber <= 0) {
            $showPostFrom = 0;
            $pageNumber = 1;
          }

          else if($pageNumber > $postPerPage) {
            $pageNumber = $pageNumber - 1;
            $showPostFrom = $pageNumber*5-5;
          }

          $ViewQuery = "select * from admin_panel order by id desc limit $showPostFrom, 5";

        } else if(isset($_GET['category'])) {
          $category = $_GET['category'];
          $ViewQuery = "select * from admin_panel where category = '$category' order by id desc";

        } else {
          $ViewQuery = "select * from admin_panel order by id desc limit 0,5";
        }

        $execute = mysqli_query($connection, $ViewQuery);

        while($DataRows = mysqli_fetch_array($execute)) {
          $id = $DataRows["id"];
          $datetime = $DataRows["datetime"];
          $title = $DataRows["title"];
          $category = $DataRows["category"];
          $author = $DataRows["author"];
          $image = $DataRows["image"];
          $post = $DataRows["post"];
      ?>

      <div class="blogpost img-thumbnail">
        <?php $flag = false;?>
        <img src="upload/<?php echo $image?>" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" alt="Responsive image"/>
        <div class="caption">
          <h3 id="heading"><?php echo htmlentities($title); ?></h3>
          <p class="description">Category:<?php echo htmlentities($category); ?><span style="margin-left:5px; float:right;">Published on:
            <?php echo htmlentities($datetime);?></span>
          </p>
          <p class="post"><?php if(strlen($post) > 150) {
            $post = substr($post, 0, 150)."...";
            $flag = true;
          }
           echo htmlentities($post);?></p>
        </div>
```

This is the site im using for my back end
https://github.com/Anik-Roy/CMS-BLOG

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](https://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Sure man. Ill look into how to change. Thanks for letting me know . Havent work with php for a while

Answer (score 0):

**Replace the code you provided with this:**

```
<?php
        global $connection;

        if(isset($_GET['Submit'])) {
          $search = $_GET['Search'];
          $ViewQuery = "select * from admin_panel
            where datetime like '%$search%' or title like '%$search%' or category like '%$search%'
            or author like '%$search%' or post like '%$search%' order by id desc";
        } else if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
          $pageNumber = $_GET['page'];
          $showPostFrom = $pageNumber*5-5;

          global $connection;
          $queryPagination = "select count(*) from admin_panel";
          $executePagination = mysqli_query($connection, $queryPagination);
          $rowPagination = mysqli_fetch_array($executePagination);
          $totalPost = array_shift($rowPagination);
          $postPerPage = ceil($totalPost/5);

          if($pageNumber <= 0) {
            $showPostFrom = 0;
            $pageNumber = 1;
          }

          else if($pageNumber > $postPerPage) {
            $pageNumber = $pageNumber - 1;
            $showPostFrom = $pageNumber*5-5;
          }

          $ViewQuery = "select * from admin_panel order by id desc limit $showPostFrom, 5";

        } else if(isset($_GET['category'])) {
          $category = $_GET['category'];
          $ViewQuery = "select * from admin_panel where category = '$category' order by id desc";

        } else {
          $ViewQuery = "select * from admin_panel order by id desc limit 0,5";
        }

        $execute = mysqli_query($connection, $ViewQuery);
        $qr = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id = $category";
        $ctgr = mysqli_query($connection, $qr);
        while($x = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ctgr)){
            $nm = $x['name'];
            $desc = $x['description'];
            $tist = $x['creatorname'];
        }
        ?>
        
                   <div class='ctgr_info' style="border-radius: 20px; width: 95vw;">
               <h1 style="font-weight: 900;"><?php echo $nm; ?></h1>
               <p><?php echo $desc; ?></p>
               <h3>Created By: <?php echo $tist; ?></h3>
           </div>
        
        <?php

        while($DataRows = mysqli_fetch_array($execute)) {
          $id = $DataRows["id"];
          $datetime = $DataRows["datetime"];
          $title = $DataRows["title"];
          $category = $DataRows["category"];
          $author = $DataRows["author"];
          $image = $DataRows["image"];
          $post = $DataRows["post"];
      ?>

      <div class="blogpost img-thumbnail">
        <?php $flag = false;?>
        <img src="upload/<?php echo $image?>" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" alt="Responsive image"/>
        <div class="caption">
          <h3 id="heading"><?php echo htmlentities($title); ?></h3>
          <p class="description">Category:<?php echo htmlentities($category); ?><span style="margin-left:5px; float:right;">Published on:
            <?php echo htmlentities($datetime);?></span>
          </p>
          <p class="post"><?php if(strlen($post) > 150) {
            $post = substr($post, 0, 150)."...";
            $flag = true;
          }
           echo htmlentities($post);?></p>

        </div>
```

**or, in simple words, just put this:**

```
$qr = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id = $category";
    $ctgr = mysqli_query($connection, $qr);
    while($x = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ctgr)){
        $nm = $x['name'];
        $desc = $x['description'];
        $tist = $x['creatorname'];
    }
    ?>
    
               <div class='ctgr_info' style="border-radius: 20px; width: 95vw;">
           <h1 style="font-weight: 900;"><?php echo $nm; ?></h1>
           <p><?php echo $desc; ?></p>
           <h3>Created By: <?php echo $tist; ?></h3>
       </div>
    
    <?php
```

**After**

```
$execute = mysqli_query($connection, $ViewQuery);
```

that's all I could do without a **minimal reproducable sample**